# How to display keyboard for editing of 'right detail' style UITableViewCell? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I'm using `storyboard` to create a grouped `UITableView`. Within the table I have several different cells setup with the 'right detail' style. I have also added IBOutlets to the `UILabels` on the right of these cells, however when someone presses the cell there's no way of editing them.

Here is what the cells look like:

[image]

I need a way of allowing the user to edit the value on the right when they press the row in the table (similar to that of the 'Contacts' application on iPhone when you edit phone numbers etc.).

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UILabel` object does not support user editing.  If you need a text field that the user can edit using the keyboard, you need to use a `UITextField` or a `UITextView`.